# css3 mediaqueries - what browsers need the js-file?

Tags: css, media-queries

hey guys,
I'm browsing with chrome and so spoiled with native css mediaqueries support.
However I want all browsers to work with mediaqueries... so I'm using

```
<script src="/js/css3-mediaqueries.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Since this file has a rather large filesize I wonder if I can use conditional tags to include this file.

like …

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="/js/css3-mediaqueries.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Do I have to consider any other important browser that do not support media queries? How about mobile android browsers etc. I know Safari, Firefox and Chrome support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this website. It will give you a list of browsers that support Media Queries.

http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS3%20Media%20Queries